# Can I use the image built for the Xiaomi Redmi 2 on the Redmi 2 pro?

Tags: compatibility, redmi-2

It seems that the only difference between the Xiaomi Redmi 2 and the Xiaomi Redmi 2 pro is that the pro version has more internal storage and more RAM. So I suppose I can use the same cyanogenmod image that was built for the Redmi 2 and use it on the Redmi 2 pro, is that right?

Would I have any issues? (Like, would it use only half of the internal storage?)

Comment: A firmware does already know how to repartition the available storage, so yes, you may have less storage available, for starters.

Comment: The 2 devices are incompatible. Something's may work, but other things won't. There are more differences in the devices than just storage and RAM. Most likely the ROM used for one on the other will cause a bootloop (the RAM is different). This is why there isn't a universal ROM for all devices. Do yourself a favor and just don't try it, unless of course you like headaches and a device that won't work. I'm on the mobile app, otherwise I would post this as an answer with additional details and proper references. Good luck.

Comment: @Jay please find a different link to use for your phone specs. Its in Spanish and doesn't show correct spec's. Use gsmarena.com or similar website. It will allow side-by-side comparison of the devices.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN: sorry, I only realized when I saw your comment! The specs are in Portuguese (I live in Brazil). I'll try to find other links.